# Zeppelin 0.7.1 does not highlight according to code syntax

Tags: syntax-highlighting, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-zeppelin

I just installed Zeppelin 0.7.1 through HDP and Ambari and the code highlights dont work anymore. Code runs normally but there is no highlights anymore for some reason. Any suggestions what components I should look at to fix this?

Edit:

I just noticed that this problem only applies for yarn-client mode. In local mode the highlighting works fine.

Comment: I faced this issue few times.  

1. when I didn't bind interpreters 2. or sometimes it worked after refreshing the browser

Comment: I just noticed that it only happens for yarn-client. Highlighting works  well for local mode. Weird.